# which version of weka tool is suitable for adding new algorithm to it, developer or stable ?

Tags: algorithm, weka

I want to modify Apriori algorithm and add it as new algorithm into weka . I don't have any idea about How can I do that also which version of weka should I have to use , either stable or developer one , currently I have weka 3.4 installed on my system . can I add a modified algorithm to weka 3.4 ? waiting to hear your help. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The web page at http://weka-addnewalgorithm.blogspot.co.uk/ claims to tell you how to add a new algorithm to Weka 3.4. I would go with the latest stable version. I would go with a stable version so if I make a mistake and break something I can be pretty sure it's something I have done, and not a bug in Weka itself.

Comment: Thank u for your suggestion . I tried to do following the steps available in the aforementioned link  but for the last 2 days I have been struggling for this error when I try to compile it gives me  "package java_cup.runtime does not exist ".

Comment: If I do jar vft weka.jar | find "cup" I find that my weka.jar file contains java_cup.runtime. (My weka, which I last used some years ago, is 3.6.6). Are you sure that you have got weka.jar on your classpath when you compile? Are you sure this weka.jar is undamaged?

Comment: I added the java-cup, jFlex and Junit to the class path now the build is successful but am facing another thing at step 21 in the specfied link inorder to aware weka a new cluster pakage is added . in my case new Association package is added , to do that I have to add superclass/interface key into the weka/gui/GenericProperitesCreator.props file. but when I open GenericProperitesCreator.props file when I open the file in neat beans  only  weka.associations.Associator=\weka.associations are found under   lists the Associators-Packages I want to choose from. so, what shall I do?